# can't connect to Sql Sever Management Express 2012

Tags: sql-server

i installed Sql Sever Management Express 2012  , but when i try to connect in Sql management studio enviroment , i have this error .

### > TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to ..

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

---

The system cannot find the file specified

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

...................................................................................

and in during installion i dont have option for select cluster !!

this is my SQL Server Configuration Manager , my sql server service is empty ...

And when get Remove a Failover Cluster Node , this error happened .

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2lrvat.jpg

Answer (score 1):

For a non-Express SQL Server installation you can just put in the server and it will connect to the default instance. For a SQL Express installation you have to specify the sever and instance name.

[image]

Comment: What is instance default name ? i enter the sever name to put it here , but it dont work !

Comment: SQLEXPRESS is the default instance name for a MS SQL Server Express install.

Comment: when i enter SQLEXPRESS  , i have same errorr :(

Comment: \
Cannot connect to SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

\